# Basis for $O_{Q[\alpha]}$ existence theorem reference

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Theorem 13 from Marcus Number fields

"This is an integral basis

$1,\frac{f_{1}(\alpha)}{d_{1}},\frac{f_{2}(\alpha)}{d_{2}},...,\frac{f_{n-1}(\alpha)}{d_{n-1}}$ ,where $f_{i}$ monic and $d_{i-1}|d_{i}$."

Does it have a name? Can you post some links about it? I am having a hard time finding it.
Thanks

Comment: Not all of us have Marcus--can you add more context?

Comment: Thm on page 6 http://math.arizona.edu/~rta/001/arnold.trevor/trevor.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Elementary divisors theorem.